# assignment syntax would that mean any code?

Tags: mithril.js

assignment syntax would that mean any code?

> While both basic assignment syntax and … can be used to the same
>   effect, typically it's recommended that you use the assignment syntax
>   whenever possible, as it's easier to read.

https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.request.html

---

**I added**

When the assignment syntax possible？

**user.json**

```
[{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Mary"}]
```

**index.html**

```
var users = m.request({method: "GET", user.json});
console.log( users() ); // undefined
```

---

**I added**

「typically it's recommended that you use the assignment syntax whenever possible」 means Code below？

**user.json**

```
[{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Mary"}]
```

**index.html**

```
var users = m.request({method: "GET", url: "user.json"}, initialValue: []});
console.log( users() );
```

or

```
var users = m.request({method: "GET", url: "user.json"}, initialValue: [{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Mary"}]});
console.log( users() );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is assignment syntax:

```
var users = m.request({method: "GET", url: "/user"});
```

This is the thennable syntaxe

```
var users = m.prop([]); //default value
m.request({method: "GET", url: "/user"}).then(users)
```

Comment: When the assignment syntax possible? I think always 「getter-setter holds an undefined value until the AJAX request completes」.so there is no choice but to use thennable syntax. I want to know How to use AJAX request assignment syntax 「getter-setter value is not undefined」

Comment: your example seems broken. `m.request` need an object with an url and optionally some data to make the ajax request to the server! Moreover, m.request gives you a promize that will be resolved when the request end. So right after the call to m.request the value is undefined (you can use initialValue to define an initial value)

Comment: I made modifications.「typically it's recommended that you use the assignment syntax whenever possible」 means define an initial value?